Two instances of the same struct with same field values in are not bitwise-equal
I have a code where i want to CAS atomic struct (Update) and it returns false. That happens with expected and atomic structs having same field values (tested with one thread).
I went to cpprefernce and it told that swap would only happen

if those are bitwise-equal

And this got me to this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct Update;
struct Info;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


enum class State { CLEAN };

struct Update { 
    State state = State::CLEAN;
    Info* info = nullptr;
};

struct Info {};

int main() {
    Update up1, up2;
    cout << (std::memcmp(&up1, &up2, sizeof(Update)) == 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}

Using clang version 19.1.0 (Fedora 19.1.0-1.fc41) Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu this code returns 0, which is why it returns false on CAS. But if i delete return 0; line it returns 1. g++ always return 1. This got me rly confused. Is that UB? Or what am i doing wrong?
If they are supposed to be different bitwise how do I use it in CAS?

Careful with the terminology. Where you write returns 0 and returns 1 I think you really mean to write prints 0 and prints 1. There's only one return in the program and if it's not always returning 0, you've got bigger problems.

What does a debugger show for the clang version? I'm wondering if they are actually initialized (even with the explicit assignment in the struct body). I would also wonder if this changes if you make the line "Update up1{}, up2{};"

This shouldn't be a problem. atomic_ref and atomic (since C++20) will compare the value representation, not the object representation. So any padding will be ignored, which is not true for memcmp.

Can you show the actual code using atomic_ref that is failing? Because I don't think what you describe should be happening.

@SoronelHaetir Using initialization with {} instead of default-initialization will have the exact same effect: Either of these initializes the members according to the default member initializers as specified in the class, but will not initialize any padding (and it isn't clear how much meaning there is to initializing padding anyway, because it is not guaranteed to be stable).

This looks to be a known bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/30023

A dupe?

@NathanOliver Aggregate initialization does not zero-initialize. It only initializes element-by-element. That would be true for value-initialization, but {} is only value-initialization if the class type is not aggregate.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

@user17732522 Good call, missed the aggregate step was before value initialization.

Structs can have padding between or after fields, due to alignment.  On a 64-bit machine, a pointer will be 8 bytes with alignof(Info*) = 8, and sizeof(enum) is only 4.  There's no guaranteed what garbage will be left in padding in a struct even after you value-initialize the members.
CAS failure due to mismatch in padding is normal for structs that have any.  If you're only using it in retry loops and the occasional retry is ok, you're fine.  Retries cost performance (and contention), but there's also a cost to telling the compiler what value the spare bytes need to be at all times.  (And sometimes a benefit for non-atomic instances of the struct; compilers sometimes avoid using one SIMD vector store to e.g. copy or zero a whole struct if there's padding.)
C++20 actually changes CAS to only compare the value bits, which GCC implements for atomic<T> by storing zeros into any padding before assignment or RMW, so the atomic object-representation always has zeros.  And normalizing a CAS input the same way makes those bytes always match.
This is done rather inefficiently as discussed in comments, but even if done optimally with AND masking of registers, it would still have a cost that might be higher than just declaring a member instead of having padding, taking responsibility yourself for having always-matching zeros at those positions.  (So when compiling a function that takes a struct arg, it can just use those bytes as-is.)  So you might still want to declare your own padding even in C++20, in cases where you can't reorder the members to avoid padding in the first place.  (What matters here is that padding exists at all, even after the last member.)
Clang doesn't do any of this, keeping the pre-C++20 behaviour of comparing the whole object representation so it doesn't have to spend extra instructions normalizing structs with padding.  This is a bug, or at least a non-compliance with the standard.

You can avoid it with an extra 4-byte member.  But only when pointers are wider than enums; you want the whole struct to be 8 bytes (4-byte enum + 4-byte pointer) when pointers are 4 bytes (e.g. AArch64 ILP32, or 32-bit targets).
Or, often the best for efficiency, make the integer member be pointer-width.  Instead of an actual enum class, use intptr_t to hold values.  You then have to manually convert to an enum class in some places if you don't want this change to infect your whole project.  The performance downside of loading a 64-bit integer instead of 32-bit from this struct is negligible, and also fine to use for temporaries in functions where you used auto.  (x86-64 will just waste some code-size on REX prefixes, AArch64 not even that.)  You don't want to make arrays of it, or waste space in other structs if there wouldn't be padding, though.
struct Update { 
    intptr_t state = State::CLEAN;
    Info* info = nullptr;
};

(You can static_assert that intptr_t is the same size as a pointer, although I don't know of any exotic platforms where it has to be bigger than a non-char pointer in order to hold pointers of any type, especially not where people would be using C++11 std::atomic.)

GNU extension only: zero size array when padding size should be 0
x86 (32-bit) MSVC reports: error C2229: struct 'Update' has an illegal zero-sized array, although most code doesn't care about 32-bit x86 anymore and MSVC does compile it just fine for 64-bit targets.
We can define a char array that fills the space where the ABI's layout rules would have put padding.  But we need its size to be zero if no padding had been needed (like your code on a 32-bit system like ARM), otherwise we're bumping up the struct from 8 to 12 bytes for example, larger than 2 pointers (which is the typical size limit for lock-free atomic operations on CPUs that support anything wider than 1 pointer-width).
GNU C/C++ allows arrays of zero size to take no space in struct, so it and the following member have the same address. So if you're only using GCC / Clang / ICX, especially if you're already using other GNU extensions, this is something to consider.  Fortunately it doesn't compile at all on MSVC if the size would be 0, rather than having a size of 1 and making your struct non-lock-free.  (In this case, if you only care about AArch64 and x86-64 (which MSVC calls x64), it's fine, the size will be non-0 so your code compiles.  You only get an error when targeting 32-bit x86.)
struct Update { 
    State state = State::CLEAN;
    char padding_ [(0 - sizeof(State)) % alignof(Info*)] = {};
    Info* info = nullptr;
};

If this is too cluttered, you can do it this way.  This still hard-codes the fact that there's only one State member before the Info*; if you add a member, you still need to manually update that to include its size: (0 - sizeof(State) - sizeof(foo) - sizeof(bar)) % alignof(Info*).
struct Update { 
  // you could make this private: if you want.
    static const size_t padding_size_ = (0 - sizeof(State)) % alignof(Info*);

    State state = State::CLEAN;
    char padding_ [(0 - sizeof(State)) % alignof(Info*)] = {};
    Info* info = nullptr;
    //static const auto foo = offsetof(Update, padding_); // can't be used from within the struct declaration

};
// try adding 1 to the padding size to see that this works
static_assert( sizeof(struct Update) == 
  sizeof(Update::state) + sizeof(Update::padding_) + sizeof(Update::info),
  "unaccounted-for padding");

In the general case for different State size (but still making some assumptions about ABI rules for struct layout not e.g. aligning char[] or over-aligning pointers), the amount of padding we want is 0 to  alignof(pointer)-1.  The unsigned modulo does that.  (Signed modulo of a negative number can be negative, so we don't want that.  But size_t is an unsigned type.)
I'm using "byte" as a unit to simplify discussion; sizeof() actually counts in units of sizeof(char) which (at least in older revisions) could be more than 8 bits, e.g. 16 or 24 on some DSPs.
For an 8-byte pointer with 8-byte alignment, we'll have 8 - sizeof(State) bytes of padding, assuming the size of the first member is from 1 to 8 bytes.  So we could do alignof(Info*) - sizeof(State).  But what if we eventually make State bigger, so 8-size is a huge unsigned value.  (size_t is an unsigned type, so subtraction wraps at zero, not producing a negative value).  That's why we modulo.
But alignof(Info*) % alignof(Info*) is 0, and adding any multiple of alignof(Info*) to the left operand of % alignof(Info*) doesn't change the result.  So we might as well just simplify to - or 0 - .  The literal 0 gets promoted to match size_t before subtraction, e.g. unsigned long.
Godbolt shows it gives an 8-byte struct with clang -m32, and it does have a 4-byte padding member when compiling for x86-64.  (And that MSVC compiles it for x64, but not for x86).
And I tested the static_assert: it fails if we change the padding size.

My understanding is that std::atomic's compare_exchange will properly ignore padding since C++20. So given that they need to use atomic anyway and can't use memcmp for the CAS, that should also avoid the issue.

Per this a zero size array is not legal.

Yes, the zero-size array is a GCC extension.

"there isn't a rule that struct members need to have different addresses.": Actually yes there is and the zero-size array behavior of GCC then seems to violate that rule. Only potentially-overlapping subobjects can share an address with another subobject. Potentially-overlapping subobjects are only base class subobjects and members with the [[no_unique_address]] attribute.

@user17732522: Thanks for the correction, I was in a hurry writing this answer.  I was thinking this wasn't going to work due to a unique-address rule, but only tried it with GCC and assumed.  Any suggestion on an alternative, or should I just mark that whole section of the answer as GCC only? Re: C++20: compare_exchange_strong is still going to compile to a 16-byte operand-size atomic RMW (like x86-64 lock cmpxchg16b) if it's lock-free at all, but maybe the object format in std::atomic<> has its padding normalized to zero, and the expected / desired operands get the same treatment?

I'll investigate if there's any practical issue with C++20 on real compilers, if not then I won't recommend trying to avoid padding with dummy member at all.  But just out of curiosity, is there a conditional-compilation way other then #if to make a member not be part of a struct at all?  Hmm, I could make the enum part of a union with a pointer-sized object, but IDK if that would be better or worse!

@user17732522: re: padding and C++20: atomic_ref on a struct where non-atomic operations might have left non-zero padding could lead to failures, unless the compiler generates extra instructions to somehow do something about this, or never lets padding be non-zero?

@PeterCordes: gcc emits instructions to zero the padding on every store to an atomic object, and does the same for the arguments to a compare-exchange.  (Though it does so in a bizarrely inefficient way, by storing zeros to the stack and loading them back, when a simple and would suffice: https://godbolt.org/z/EMYYo6T6K).  As noted, that's necessary for C++20 conformance, where the value representation is to be compared.  clang's failure to do the same is apparently a bug.

@NateEldredge: Ok, so the cure is about as bad as the disease, if not worse (at least for low-contention cases; it does avoid retries).  So yeah we definitely still want to avoid padding in structs!  (Especially with clang being buggy and GCC being inefficient).  Even if compilers handled it optimally, it still might be worse than having objects get their padding set to zero when created and never having it changed.  Compilers also tend to do better at using SIMD vectors to zero a whole non-atomic object when there's no padding.

@NateEldredge: For correctness at least, could a CAS compile to a plain store of 0 to the padding, before the CAS instruction?  That would suck for performance in a lot of cases, including being a store-forwarding stall if the uarch allows the load side of the CAS to store-forward, otherwise a stall to drain the store buffer.  Normally inventing stores is a big no-no, but this is only to padding, not to any value bits.  It creates extra ordering, and makes even a failed CAS dirty the cache line on LL/SC ISAs where it might not.

Hmm.  Inventing a store like that certainly sounds bad, but I agree that I can't actually come up with a case where it would break.  (Unless the object happens to also be volatile, of course.)  It might take several store instructions depending on the amount and location of padding. And if there are bitfields, so that the padding is not integral bytes, we might even need an atomic RMW.

@PeterCordes: Oh, I messed up my previous example by accidentally declaring a return type and not returning a value: UB.  Here's a better one: https://godbolt.org/z/fs5McY5eo.  So with atomic_ref<A>, unlike atomic<A>, upon CAS failure they do normalize the loaded value and see if it is equal (mod padding) to expected, and if so they retry the CAS.  (With weird inefficiencies throughout, including redundant tests.)  Thus actually I guess it's okay.

I guess the inefficiency comes from __builtin_clear_padding: https://godbolt.org/z/YdEs86Gxb

@NathanOliver: updated my answer, thanks to you and user17732522 for the correction.
